# How can I list matching column names across two data frames?

Tags: r, match

I have two data frames (`x` and `y`).

When I need to join data, one of the first things I do is to look and see what the common column (field) names are for any obvious ones (such as `x$id` and `y$id`).

I can check to see how many columns `x` and `y` share like this:

```
library(dplyr)

colnames(x) %in% colnames(y) %>% table
```

Which gives:

```
> colnames(x) %in% colnames(y) %>% table
.
FALSE  TRUE 
    5    12
```

However, how can I list the names of the matching columns to see which ones they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intersect the lists of column name

```
intersect( colnames(x),  colnames(y))
```